# jquery Hover bug

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to write a piece of Jquery that will change something when the user hovers on/hover off a div.

However if i hover off the div during the animation the hover on animation the off animation does not work

```
$('.boxgrid').hover(function(){
    $(".cover", this).stop().delay(1000).animate({top:'80px'},{queue:true,duration:500});
}, function() {
    $(".cover").stop().animate({top:'130px'},{queue:false,duration:0});
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should accept an answer. read the faq at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `.stop()`'s to `.stop(true, true)`.

Comment: Nice one. Seems to have done the trick. What does the '(true,true)' do?

Comment: The true clears the animation queue, and the seconds skips to the end of the animation - http://api.jquery.com/stop/ BTW, check my answer.

Comment: I will, Says I have to wait seven mins

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CKrPF/ - does this not work correctly?

Comment: Please avoid posting link as answer. If jsFiddle changes his URL pattern, your answer will contain no information at all. Also the code is fairly small, you can simply just post it in your answer.